# Two different jquery.js fle in a same html file

Tags: jquery, html, web

I am trying to add a photo slider from Wowslider that use jQuery v1.8.3 in my website that has a navigation menu based on jQuery but I don't know the exact version (here is the [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-cool-animated-navigation-with-css-and-jquery/) where I took the source files )

When comment out one of the two jquery.js files the other one works fine. However, together something is going wrong
I can't make a slider from Wowoslider and an animations menu work together correctly.

The code in my HTML is these. the problems comes with js/jquery.js(unknown version) and engine1/jquery.js(1.8.3 version)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-bp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/navigation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="date_time.js"></script>
    <!-- Start WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- End WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->
</head>
```

**I try this [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)**

The solution seems simple but i can't understand this

Then, instead of `$('#selector').function();`, you'd do `jQuery_1_3_2('#selector').function();` or `jQuery_1_1_3('#selector').function();`.

I change my including scripts code in my html like this:

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.2.3 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_2_3 = $.noConflict(true);
    </script>
            <!-- ...other code... -->
    <!-- load jQuery 1.8.3 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_8_2 = $.noConflict(true);
    </script>
```

Then i try to change the code of 2 .js file that use jQuery 1.2.3
so i replace all the `$` chars with this `jQuery_1_2_3`

an sort example default is

> (function($) {
>       $.extend($.fx.step,{
>           backgroundPosition: function(fx) {
>               if (fx.state === 0 && typeof fx.end == 'string') {
>                   var start = $.curCSS(fx.elem,'backgroundPosition');

And i change to this:

`(function(jQuery_1_2_3) {
    jQuery_1_2_3.extend(jQuery_1_2_3.fx.step,{
        backgroundPosition: function(fx) {
            if (fx.state === 0 && typeof fx.end == 'string') {
                var start = jQuery_1_2_3.curCSS(fx.elem,'backgroundPosition');`

I think i understand something wrong.. Steel dont working..

Comment: If you insist on using two versions of jQuery in your site you'll need to invoke jQuery.noConflict(). Here are the docs - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ Other than that if you'll post the relevant code and markup we'll try to help you solve this.

Comment: The one from the site is 1.2.3.  Very old.  Try to just use the 1.8.3 if you can.

Comment: Also I Firefox browser work together the slider and the navigation menu without obvious problems.. I want find a solution tou work at most common browsers. like chrome safari....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I came up with a solution which is tested by my self. I check your Menu Tutorial and Downloaded the Source Code then I use Wow Slider in Same Page but my way is as:

// Add below code in Top of Head

```
<!-- Navigation Menu-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-bp.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/navigation.js" ></script>
<!-- End Navigation -->
```

// And Add Wow Slider Script in the Bottom of Page

```
<!-- Start WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- End WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>
<!-- End WOWSlider.com BODY section -->
```

Now do some changes in 'navigation.js'

1) Write all the functions inside

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
  // all navigation function put here

  });
})(jQuery);
// other code using $ as an alias to the other library
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

I uploaded my code for you on this link. Please [Download](https://www.box.com/s/fhhunnlwgex35exwhzwr) and let me know it's working for you or not.. for me it's working on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Dear @Neeraj Singh I change my navigation.js with yours and i make the changes in my index.html ! steel no working for me. But your demo code is working fine with firefox & Ghrome! I am goining to check it again!   I find a semi-solution with putting the newer jQuery.js first in order and then the older(navigations jQuerty) That give me a delay at navigation motion but almost working and the slider is working good but the bullets of slider dont work.

Comment: Why must put the Wowslider jQuerty at the end of body? Make any difference to put that in the <<middle of <body> >> right then my wowslider <body> code?